# Using read.xlsx in Shiny R App

Tags: r, excel, spreadsheet, summary, shiny

I am trying to load an excel file and display the summary. The file is loading without any errors but not displaying anything.

Here is my code

ui.R

```
library(shiny)
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
     headerPanel("Analysis"),
     sidebarPanel(wellPanel(fileInput('file1', 'Choose XLSX File',
          accept=c('sheetName', 'header'), multiple=FALSE))),
mainPanel(
tabsetPanel(
  tabPanel("Tab1",h4("Summary"), htmlOutput("summary"))    
)))
```

server.R

```
      library(shiny)


shinyServer(function(input, output) {
 dataset = reactive({

    infile = input$file1  


    if (is.null(infile))
      return(NULL)

    infile_read = read.xlsx(infile$datapath, 1)
    return(infile_read)

  })

 output$summary <- renderPrint({
   summary = summary(dataset())
   return(summary)
 })

  outputOptions(output, "summary", suspendWhenHidden = FALSE)

})
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested this, but it looks like you're not actually returning anything from `dataset()`. Change the function to:

```
dataset = reactive({

  infile = input$file1  

  if (is.null(infile))
    return(NULL)

  read.xlsx(infile$datapath, 1)

})
```

When you do `infile_read = read.xlsx(infile$datapath, 1)`, you're reading the file into `infile_read` but then you're not actually returning it. Reactives work just look any R function really. Try running this:

```
f <- function() x <- 10
f()
```

You should see that `f()` doesn't return anything. All it's doing is making an assignment that goes nowhere. To actually return `'hello'` you would do:

```
f <- function() {
  x <- 'hello'
  x
}
```

Or just:

```
f <- function() 'hello'
```

Comment: I have also tried the following, but no luck                 `infile_read = read.xlsx(infile$datapath, 1)
    return(infile_read)`

Comment: Put `browser()` right after where you read in the file. Is the file definitely being read in?

Comment: I included `browser()` its showing Browser> in command line and just stopping there. No errors, no output. I have also tried `browser(text = "Done!!")`, but the "Done!!" is not printing.

Comment: Okay, good, that's what's supposed to happen. Now poke around and see what you find. For example, at the browser prompt, try typing `infile$datapath` and see if you get a valid path to a file that exists. Try typing `infile_read` and see if you get a `data.frame` object.