# fileInput: How to create a dataframe from a .xlsx file within shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

I am very new to shiny and ran quite fast in a problem which impedes to continue my work. I created a .xlsx file and tried to load this within shiny.
A similar problem was dicussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18727284/using-read-xlsx-in-shiny-r-app) but was not finally solved.

I tried to keep the code as simple as possible:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
      fileInput("uploadFile", "XLSX file"),
      verbatimTextOutput("summary")
      )

server <- function(input, output) ({

          dataset<-reactive({ 
          inFile <- input$uploadFile 
          dat<-read.xlsx("inFile$datapath", 1)
          return(dat)
          })

         output$summary <- renderText({summary(dataset())})

         })
```

Just loading the .xlsx file in R works fine with this code:

```
read.xlsx("testdata.xlsx", 1)
```

Adding `browser()` after `inFile <- input$uploadFile` in `server`and calling `inFile` gives I think the correct object which contains `.$datapath`. 
The error I get after uploading the file is:

```
Error in loadWorkbook(file) : Cannot find inFile$datapath
```

I hope this is not to silly but I just can figure out how to solve it. What I would like to know is how can I store my uploaded file as a dataframe within shiny?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should leave the "" from the `dat<-read.xlsx("inFile$datapath", 1)` line.

This one works:

```
dat<-read.xlsx(inFile$datapath, 1)
```

Best,
Róbert